# Run aws cli v1 and v2 in same docker image

Tags: docker, shell, aws-cli, alpine-linux

I have built an image with both aws cli v1 and v2 installed.

- aws cli v1 at /usr/bin
- aws cli v2 at /usr/local/bin

Now, I'd like to `docker run` to set a default aws cli version if possible with an environment variable to switch with.

Such as :

```
# docker run -ti --rm -e version=v2 awscli_image bash
$ which aws
/usr/local/bin/aws

# docker run -ti --rm -e version=v1 awscli_image bash
$ which aws
/usr/bin/aws
```

Any suggestions to make this work?

So the question becomes to ask for how to adjust `PATH` variable in a running container. It would be a generic request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most robust way to approach this is to maintain two separate images, one with each version of the CLI tool.  Then there's no questions around which thing comes first in `$PATH`, and the images themselves won't contain versions of the tool you're not using.

```sh
docker run --rm awscli_image:v1 aws sts get-caller-identity
docker run --rm awscli_image:v2 aws sts get-caller-identity
```

If they really have to be in the same image, you can use an entrypoint wrapper script to look at the environment variable setting.  If you set the image's `ENTRYPOINT` to be a shell script, [it will get passed the `CMD` as arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact), and the script can end with `exec "$@"` to actually run the `CMD`.

For your example, you could write a wrapper like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Push something on to $PATH depending on the environment
case "$version" in
  v1) PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH" ;;
  v2) PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" ;;
esac
# Then run the CMD
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, `COPY` this script in as normal and set it as the `ENTRYPOINT`.

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"] # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["aws", "--help"]
```

Comment: yes, I want to avoid to build two images. Let me test the entrypoint script first

Comment: works, thanks a lot. By the way, the case statement should be `in`, not `of`